# JSF component value not properly updated to model upon submit

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I have facelets page with a control that usually is disabled by default, i. e. when the page is first rendered to the client. This is determined by an EL expression:

```
disabled="#{referenceValue != requestbean.dependentControlValue}" id="notWorking"
```

After the page is rendered, the user can set the `requestbean.dependentControlValue` to `referenceValue` and via some Javascript for the dependent control, the component "notWorking" is enabled.

However, upon submitting the form the value for `notWorking` does not get updated as found out by adding a debug log message in the setter for the value. I can see, that the value for `notWorking` is set in the request when inspecting it with firefox.

**Question:** 
What am I doing wrong?

By the way:
I know that according to HTML specification, disabled controls cannot be successful thanks to the research here on StackOverflow.

Moreover, I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/2108919), that the `disabled` and `rendered` expressions are considered before updating the model values, but I think the disabled expression should evaluate to `false` upon submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong?*

Using JavaScript instead of JSF to re-enable the input.

As part of JSF's builtin safeguard against tampered/hacked HTTP requests, the `disabled` attribute is (like `rendered` and `readonly` attributes) re-evaluated during processing the form submit. If they evaluate in such way that the value shouldn't be processed at all (i.e. `disabled/readonly=true` and `rendered=false`, then the submitted value won't be applied, converted, validated and the model won't be updated.

The solution would be to use JSF instead of JavaScript to re-enable the input, or to rewrite the condition in `disabled` attribute in such way so that the `disabled` attribute evaluates `false` during processing the form submit.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, especially for revising your answer to precisely answer my question. So, using jsf 2, I'd simply use a partial request triggered from dependent control with re-rendering the `notWorking` component. How could I implement your solution with jsf1.2?